# d3js onmouseover highlight not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a table with row and column head texts which have ids like `row3`, `col1`, ...

I'm using

```
.on("mouseover", highlight)
```

on a rect inside the table, and the function looks like this:

```
function highlight(d){

  var txt = d3.select("#col"+d3.select(this).attr("colNr"));
  txt.style('fill', 'darkOrange');
}
```

The `"#col"+d3.select(this).attr("colNr")` gives me the correct `"col2"` (saw it in the debugger + alert). But it seems like

```
d3.select("col2").style('fill', 'darkOrange');
```

is not changing anything for me...
Does anybody know whats wrong here?

**EDIT**:
Sorry wasn't possible to solve this without the rest of the code:
With trial and error I reduced the possible failure-sources and its something different then I thought. I think I've got a problem with the scope(?),reduced my example, it still hast the failure but here is the complete relevant javascript code:

```
<script>
var links;

var svgContainer = d3.select("div#container")
//.call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1,3]).on("zoom", redraw))
.append("svg").attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet").attr("viewBox",
        "0 0 1920 1080").classed("svg-container", true);

var g = svgContainer.append("g");

//exchange later with string
d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
    if (error)
        throw error;

    links = graph.links;

    addRects();
});

alert(links.length);

//end exchange
function addRects(){

    g.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 100)
        .attr("y", 100)
        .attr("width", 120)
        .attr("height", 80)
        .attr("fill", "#eeeeee")
        .attr("id","this1");

    g.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 300)
        .attr("y", 100)
        .attr("width", 120)
        .attr("height", 80)
        .attr("fill", "#eeeeee")
        .attr("id","this2");
}

d3.select("#this2").style("fill","#ff0000");
```

If I copy d3.select("#this2").style("fill","#ff0000"); inside the inner function (@the json part) it works. But not when its outside. I'm still struggling with this type of inner function (this is a closure, right?). I know it has its parents functions scope. But I thought for example by declaring var links; at the top(global var?) it has the links in the alert but I get "links is undefined" ... so the inner functions links is a different var?

Comment: I think it's `d3.select("#col2").style('background-color', 'darkOrange');` instead of `d3.select("col2").style('fill', 'darkOrange');`

Comment: You still haven't included the html... what is "#this2"? Also alert(links.length); is called before d3.json returns so it will always be undefined where you have it... (d3.json is asynchronous). Put alert(links.length); inside the addRects function and it will work (at least that part). I think the overall issue is that "this" doesn't point to what you think it does or you have some basic typos in your code.

Answer (score 1):

d3.select Selects the first element that matches the specified selector string. 
It expects an element type or an identifier.

So presumably you need -

```
d3.select("#col2").style('fill', 'darkOrange');
```

Notice the `#` pound sign that marks the string as an identifier.

Without it the select function is looking for an element called col2 - `<col2></col2>` - rather than an element with the id col2 - `<x id='col2'></x>` (where x is any valid element type).

Comment: Thanks, but that was only a typo here in stackoverflow... this has to work or?: 

  var txt = d3.select("#col"+d3.select(this).attr("colNr"));

Comment: If you have typos in the question it is impossible to help as how do we know what the actual issue is? The other example you give looks funky - can you post a complete example without typos?

Comment: thats true, sorry, but if you just overlook the last code snippet (wich was more for explenation wich part I think is not working), the highlight function is not working and the "#" is in there.

Comment: Can you show a clear example that shows all the relevant code without typos then? It could be a typo in your html for all I know - that said -
- d3.select(this).attr("colNr") - looks wrong, what do you think "this" is in the context of the function?